# How to combine node-turn with existing express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, peerjs, turn

I need to use a own TURN server for [peerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerjs) and I found that [node-turn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-turn) would be a better solution for that. But I would like to use the turn server along with existing express server. There is a way, we can provide the port at node-turn.

```
var server = new Turn({
     listeningPort: 8001
  }
});
```

But when I host this app on a server, listening on different port does not work. Therefore I have to implement this in another way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this one?

Comment: @rob_ No, I didn't